# How to resolve com.android.internal.R.drawable.hover_tooltip_bg?

Tags: java, android

I reset my windows station and now I can't set-up the project. I get multiply times *"hover_tooltip_bg cannot be resolved or is not a field"*.

But I don't understand in which problem is? What I should add to get definition of that?
Another part of Android library is almost OK.

Almost because I get for example:

```
FEATURE_HOVERING_UI cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

for line:

```
if ( this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_HOVERING_UI) == true) {
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are having version mismatch between your development environment and documentation you are referring. `FEATURE_HOVERING_UI` is not part of the latest version PackageManager